# One TransactionInterceptor for two Different Databases

Tags: cdi, interceptor, transactional

I'm having some headache with my Transaction Interceptor implementation. In my application I have two qualified producer methods for two different databases. Each one, @DatabaseA and @DatabaseB produces a different @RequestScoped EntityManager. So, when I want to connect to @DatabaseA I'm using...

```
@Inject @DatabaseA EntityManager em;
```

...and so on. Everything works right, but how can I figure out in my Transaction Interceptor what EntityManager use to avoid ambiguous dependency errors?

```
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionalInterceptor {

    @Inject @???
    private EntityManager em;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object proceed(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Object o = context.proceed();

        em.getTransaction().commit();

        return o;
    }
}
```

I want to use just one Interceptor in two different DAOs that must persist data into two different databases. Is it possible?

Comment: what is your java-ee version?

Comment: Hi I'm using Weld 2.4.5.Final, CDI 1.1 in Java EE 8

Comment: Doesn't that already have a @transactional annotation?

Comment: Yeah it has, but not any built-in transaction bean

Comment: That is provided by JTA...

Comment: Sure, but I'm in Tomcat... any suggestion on how to configure it with maven?

Comment: I asked what java-ee version you are using , you said java EE 8, Tomcat is **not** java EE... Please be very careful with providing the correct information. And sorry, finding out solutions for sort of creating a java-ee server in a plain servlet container is going to take too much time for me to help finding this out... Cheers

Comment: Maybe look how the transactional interceptors provided by jta work... The source of many of them is open. Or try https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html

Comment: Ok, thank you @Kukeltje :) anyone else know a way to use JTA on Tomcat or solve it with CDI?

Comment: See my comment about deltaspike. Looks very useful (deltaspike is useful in other ways too)